# How to upload an image to web resource folder in tomcat or glassfish

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, intellij-idea, glassfish

I tried to upload an image to tomcat and glassfish servers, Path I tried to set is as bellow `System.getProperty("user.dir")+ File.separator+"images"+File.separator;`

It takes `System.getProperty("user.dir")` as tomcat `C:\Apache\Tomcat\bin` and glassfish 'C:\Apache\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config` directory. I am using Intellij to develop the system.

I want to upload an image to `out/artifacts/CopywriteProtector_war)exploded/Resources/images` folder so that I can access the images using `http://localhost/Resources/images/msg.jpg`, how to do this? I have spent days of time googling but couldn't able to find useful thing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the root of your deployed application with

```
String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

This will be the equivalent of the resources directory of your source code.
Add the filepath of where you want your image to be. i.e.

```
String filePath = root + "images/msg.jpg";
```

Then you can created your writer from that path

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filepath);
writer.write(objectToWrite);//or similar
```

You can then access the resulting file  with

```
getServletContext().getResource(filePath); // as URL or
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(filePath); // as InputStream
```

-- Tested and worked on Payara (an application server derived from Glassfish)